# How do I step through CCW code from VBA into C#?

Tags: c#, vba, com, callable

My C# code is COM Callable.  It works when running the Word VBA against the installed application.  I want to step through the code from VBA into the code in the Visual Studio project.

Comment: That's not possible.  Use Project + Properties, Debug tab and select WinWord.exe as your startup program.  Set a breakpoint on the C# method(s) you want to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Put `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` in your C# code and the VS debugger will be attached to it.

Comment: How does that help?  Isn't the debugger already attached if you run in debug mode anyway?